# What's the difference between var string1 = [String]() & var string2: [String] = [] in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, string

What is the difference between:

`var string1 = [String]()`

and

`var string2: [String] = []`

in the Swift programming language?

Comment: None. Syntax only. I prefer the second one. Btw there is a 3rd one `var string3: [String] = .init()`

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29199268/swift-difference-between-var-arrstring-and-var-arr-string) . This is already answered here.

Comment: Why did people down-vote this? It is a puzzling language quirk. I can see why those learning Swift would find it confusing. (Valid to close it as a duplicate. but why down-vote it?)