# Swift String variable

Tags: swift

```
//First way
var myVar: String = " Hello"
print(myVar)
//Second way
var str = "Hello"
print(str)
```

**I get the same output no matter which of the two I use. What's the difference between them?**

Comment: Keywords: `Type Annotation` vs `Type Inference`. I made a few days ago an answer about hat https://stackoverflow.com/a/70975630/1801544 it's regarding an Array, but `"Hello"` is `String.init("Hello")`, the logic about the type is the same.

Comment: There is no difference between them (leaving the space in front of the first Hello). In the first one you declared the type of myVar to be of type String. In the second instance, you didn't specify it's type (var str).

Comment: Swift interprets the type on its own. The only type you really need to specify the type is if a) you don't give it a value, b) its some sort of dictionary, c) you want to force a numerical value to be a CGFloat, or Double, etc.

Comment: The difference is that the first one has a space at the beginning (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two are basically the same.

When you use `var myVar: String = "Hello"`, you directly tell the swift compiler that your variable is type `String`.

When you use `var myVar = "Hello"`, you do not specify the type of your variable, so the swift compiler has do do that for you.

Usually, you can get away without declaring your variable type and just have swift do it for you. However, in some cases, namely computed properties and custom classes/structures, you must manually declare your variable to be a specific type.

In your case, either way is fine. The end result is the same, just be aware of the difference for the future.

Comment: Thanks, I understood, I knew it wouldn't be a problem for now, but I wanted to go with a solid foundation.